# binary representation of binary re

Tags: binary

Is there any efficient way to find the binary representation of binary representation of a given number n ? 
Where  1 <= n <= 600000

Example : Lets take n = 2
So, binary representation of 2 is 10
Then, the answer is the binary representation of 10, i.e., 1010

Comment: Do you mean "the binary representation of (the binary representation of a number n reinterpreted as a base-10 number)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is off the top of my head, should be fast enough for most purposes.  Works for values upto and including 1,048,575.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            checked
            {
                uint i = 0;
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        BinaryOfDecimalRepresentation(++i);
                    }
                    catch { Console.WriteLine("Works until " + i); break; }
                }
                while (true)
                {
                    uint input = 0;
                    try
                    {
                        input = uint.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    catch { }
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        BinaryOfDecimalRepresentation(input) + " : " +
                        UInt64ToString(BinaryOfDecimalRepresentation(input)));
                }
            }

        }
        static ulong BinaryOfDecimalRepresentation(uint input)
        {
            checked
            {
                ulong result = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
                    if ((input & 1 << i) != 0) result += (ulong)Math.Pow(10, i);
                return result;
            }
        }

        static char[] buffer = new char[64];
        static string UInt64ToString(ulong input, bool trim = true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
                buffer[63 - i] = ((input & (ulong)1 << i) != 0) ? '1' : '0';
            int firstOne = 0;
            if (trim) while (buffer[firstOne] == '0') firstOne++;
            return new string(buffer, firstOne, 64 - firstOne);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it cause an overflow in C/C++ ?? Because pow(10,i) is using values of i greater than the bounds.

Comment: @AnkurMishra this is C# (not language was specified) and does not appear to overflow (hence the checked arithmetic).  Feel free to verify function yourself - I won't provide any guarantee.  I just improved it to work to 1 Million.

Comment: Actually i am supposed to use this thing in C/C++. So, can you please explain the algorithm a bit ??

Comment: It finds out if a bit is set, then adds the decimal value of that bit to the result.  For example if the second bit is set, it knows to add 10.  You should be able to figure out the rest, and implement it in C/C++ without my help.